# f# Cast enum element type

Tags: enums, f#

I have a question rather simple I think but I can not find any info about it.
So for example in c# I can define value enum types using inheritance like:

```
public enum RequestedService : ushort
{
    [Description("Unknown")]
    Unknown = 0,

    [Description("Status")]
    SERVICE1 = 0x0001
}
```

But how would I do it in F#, so far I translate it like:

```
type RequestedService =
    | [<Description("Unknown")>] Unknown = 0u
    | [<Description("Status")>] SERVICE1 = 0x0001u
```

I tried using inheritance, and tried to define type before value like

```
Unknown = uint16 0u
```

But I am getting compile error, so is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting of non-`int32` values to an `enum` is documented in **[Enumerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations#remarks)**:

> The default [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.enum%5B%5Eu%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function works with type `int32`. Therefore, it cannot be used with enumeration types that have other underlying types. Instead, use the following.
>
> ```
> type uColor =
>    | Red = 0u
>    | Green = 1u
>    | Blue = 2u
> let col3 = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<uint32, uColor>(2u)
> ```

Thus you would do:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives

type RequestedService =
    | [<Description("Unknown")>] Unknown = 0u
    | [<Description("Status")>] SERVICE1 = 0x0001u

let service = EnumOfValue<uint32, RequestedService>(0u) // Or 1u or whatever
```

Or if you prefer:

```
let service : RequestedService = EnumOfValue 0u // Or 1u or whatever
```

For more see: **[LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<'T,'Enum> Function](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-languageprimitives.html#EnumOfValue)**.